# Javascript to show folder and files by calling Web Api

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Javascript which call the web api to see the available folder and then the available files. Any comment or code review on my code?

```js
    var divFolder = document.getElementById("rootFolder");
    var divFiles = document.getElementById("files");

    function createFolderElement(data) {
        var li = document.createElement("div");
        li.setAttribute('data-id', data.filePathId);
        li.setAttribute('class', "folder");

        divFolder.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML = data.folderName
    }

    function createFileElement(data) {
        debugger
        var li = document.createElement("div");
        li.setAttribute('data-id', data.id);
        li.setAttribute('class', "file");

        divFiles.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML = data.fileName
    }

    async function fetchFolder(parentId) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'block'
        divFolder.innerHTML = ''

        const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:44371/api/file/folder/${parentId}`);

        if (!response.ok) {
            const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
            $("div.message").text(message);
            $("div.message").addClass("message alert alert-warning");
            //throw new Error(message);
        }

        const files = await response.json();
        if (files.length > 0) {
            files.forEach((data) => {
                createFolderElement(data)
            })

            createFolderEventListener();

            document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none'
        }
    }

    async function fetchFiles(filePathId) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'block'
        divFolder.innerHTML = ''

        const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:44371/api/file/files/${filePathId}`);

        if (!response.ok) {
            const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
            $("div.message").text(message);
            $("div.message").addClass("message alert alert-warning");
            //throw new Error(message);
        }

        const folders = await response.json();
        debugger
        if (folders.length > 0) {
            folders.forEach((data) => {
                createFileElement(data)
            })

            createFileEventListener();
        }

        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none'
    }

    function createFolderEventListener() {
        const myfolder = document.getElementsByClassName("folder");
        [...myfolder].forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener("click", function () {
                fetchFolder(element.dataset.id);
                fetchFiles(element.dataset.id);
            });
        });
    };

    function createFileEventListener() {
        const myfolder = document.getElementsByClassName("file");
        [...myfolder].forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener("click", function () {
                downloadPdf(element.dataset.id, element.textContent)
            });
        });
    };

    $(function () {
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none'
        fetchFolder(1);
    })
```

```css
    div.folder {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 2px;
        cursor: pointer
    }

    div.file {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 2px;
        cursor: pointer
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message"></div>
<img src="~/img/loading.gif" id="spinner" />
<div id="rootFolder"></div>
<div id="files"></div>
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more details and background information on what all's going on so we have some more context to work with? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance, sorry, what background information should I include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prefer modern syntax** You're using a few ES2015+ features already, including `async`/`await`. If you're going to write a script containing modern syntax (*which you should* - it can make code much easier to read and write), best to use it *everywhere*. In particular:

- Use `const` (or `let` when you need to reassign) instead of `var`. `var` has too many problems to be worth using nowadays, such as an unintuitive function scope (instead of block scope), hoisting, and implicitly creating properties on the global object when on the top level. (Use the [`no-var`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var) linting rule.)
- In ES2015+, iterators are available. Utilizing these can make code significantly more concise. For example:

  ```
  const myfolder = document.getElementsByClassName("folder");
  [...myfolder].forEach(function(element) {
  ```

  can be

  ```
  for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.folder')) {
  ```

**jQuery or not?** You're using a bit of jQuery, and a lot of vanilla JS DOM manipulation. This is odd, stylistically. One would usually expect, if jQuery is used, for it to be used *everywhere* that it can be, at least regarding the DOM. But jQuery doesn't really provide anything that can't be done just as easily in vanilla JS, so you could remove jQuery as a dependency entirely too, if you wished. (That's what I'd choose, but it's up to you.)

**Attributes** 2 things:

- When you want to assign to a `data-` attribute, consider using `dataset` instead of the more verbose `setAttribute`:

  ```
  li.setAttribute('data-id', data.filePathId);
  ```

  can be

  ```
  li.dataset.id =  data.filePathId;
  ```
- Classes can be also be set with dot notation, with `className`:

  ```
  li.setAttribute('class', "folder");
  ```

  can be

  ```
  li.className = 'folder';
  ```

**Avoid direct insertion of HTML markup** You have:

```
$("div.message").text(message);
```

That's a good way to do things - assign *text* to the text content of an element. But elsewhere, you have

```
li.innerHTML = data.folderName
```

That can result in arbitrary code execution. It can also result in formatting problems relating to HTML entities. It sounds very likely that you're expecting `folderName` to only contain a plain non-HTML string, in which case you should set *only the text* of the `<li>`:

```
li.textContent = data.folderName;
```

Even though the folder name from the API response is almost certainly trustworthy, using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` is a good habit to get into.

**Semicolons** Sometimes you're using semicolons when they're needed, and sometimes you aren't. To be stylistically consistent, best to choose one style - either use them wherever appropriate, or don't use them at all. Note that if you don't use them at all, unless you're an expert, you may well eventually run into problems due to [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). (I'd recommend using semicolons.) To enforce a particular style on your code, use [a linter](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi).

**fetchFolder and fetchFiles errors** If either the `fetchFolder` or `fetchFiles` request fails, there are 2 problems:

- You don't return or throw if the response is not OK. As a result, the `await response.json();` will throw. The control flow is odd.
- You show the spinner at the beginning of the request, but if there's an error, the code will never get to the end of the function where the spinner is hidden again.

The two functions also do very similar things - they show the spinner, do a fetch, and on error, show an error element to the user. Make things more DRY by creating a wrapper function around them.

Or, you could also consider using `Promise.all` - wait for *both* requests to complete before updating the UI, to make things look more natural to the user.

```
const fetchPath = (path) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:44371/api/${path}`);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
};
const fetchFolderAndFiles = (id) => {
    const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
    spinner.style.display = 'block';
    divFolder.textContent = '';
    await Promise.all([
        fetchPath(`files/${id}`),
        fetchPath(`folder/${id}`),
    ])
        .then(([files, folders]) => {
            showFiles(files);
            showFolders(folders);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const message = `An error has occured: ${error.message}`;
            const messageElm = document.querySelector('div.message');
            messageElm.textContent = message;
            messageElm.className = 'message alert alert-warning';
        })
        .finally(() => {
            spinner.style.display = 'block';
        });
};
```

**Don't check array length before iterating** There's no need for

```
if (folders.length > 0) {
    folders.forEach((data) => {
```

If the array is empty, no iterations will occur anyway. Surrounding the `forEach` in another `if` statement increases indentation unnecessarily and makes more unnecessary cognitive overhead.

**Duplicate listener bug** Every time `fetchFolder` is called, you also call `createFolderEventListener`, which does:

```
const myfolder = document.getElementsByClassName("folder");
[...myfolder].forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
```

So every time a folder is clicked, you're adding additional listeners to *every* folder element on the page. This will result in many unnecessary requests, and possibly more strange behavior.

Only add a listener to a folder if the folder doesn't already have a listener. Or, even better, add only a **single** listener, to a parent element, and utilize event delegation:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.target.matches('.folder')) {
        return;
    }
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    fetchFolder(
        fetchFiles(id);
    );
});
```

Run that *once*, on pageload, and then you can remove `createFolderEventListener`.

**Do the same thing** for `createFileEventListener`, which has the same problem.

**Precise variable names** You have:

```
var divFiles = document.getElementById("files");
```

and

```
function createFileEventListener() {
  const myfolder = document.getElementsByClassName("file");
```

(`createFileEventListener` should probably be removed entirely, but if it isn't, make sure to change `myfolder` to `myfile`)

Precise variable names make code easier to read and helps prevent bugs. A variable name should probably only be plural if it refers to a *collection*. Otherwise, it should be singular. Similarly, a collection should have a plural variable name. Maybe call it `filesContainer` instead of `divFiles`, and `fileDivs` instead of `myfolder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive review. Appreciate it.

Comment: For these two lines, I can't avoid to use `var` right?     `var divFolder = document.getElementById("rootFolder");
    var divFiles = document.getElementById("files");`

Comment: Sure you can, you can always avoid `var`. Use `const` instead

Comment: I will also move certain variable to the class variable like the spinner. `const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner').style.display;`